How do I fix the layout of this application?
I cannot find a way to fix the issue with centering widgets (tkinter) and positioning them around in a way that I want.
I have tried using sticky="EW", as well as padx=[value]. none of those really worked out.
It seems that there are two "containers" per page, but i don't know what to think of that.
Here's the code:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font
import math
import cmath


root = tk.Tk() #application window
page1 = tk.Frame(root, background="#545454") 
page2 = tk.Frame(root, background="#545454")
page3 = tk.Frame(root, background="#545454")
page4 = tk.Frame(root, background="#545454")

page1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
page2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
page3.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
page4.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")



#page titles
ttl1M = tk.Label(page1, text="Main Page", font=('roboto', 20), bg="#545454")
ttl1M.grid(pady=20, row=0, column=0, padx=90)

#Quadratics Page-content
qdrtcs = tk.Label(page2, text="Quadratic Page", font=('roboto', 20), bg="#545454")
qdrtcs.grid(pady=20, padx=95, row=0, column=0)

#spinboxes for A/B/C start
quadA = tk.Spinbox(page2, from_=-99, to=99, width=5, font=('roboto', 24))
quadA.grid(pady=30, row=1, column=0, sticky="n")

quadB = tk.Spinbox(page2, from_=-99, to=99, width=5, font=('roboto', 24))
quadB.grid(pady=30, row=1, column=1, sticky="n")

quadC = tk.Spinbox(page2, from_=-99, to=99, width=5, font=('roboto', 24))
quadC.grid(pady=30, row=1, column=2, sticky="n")


##########
nyi1 = tk.Label(page3, text="Simple Geometry", font=('roboto', 20), bg="#545454")
nyi1.grid(pady=20, row=0, column=0)

nyi2 = tk.Label(page4, text="Under further construction", font=('roboto', 20), bg="#545454")
nyi2.grid(pady=20, row=0, column=0)

#page buttons
quadratics_btn = tk.Button(page1, text="Quadratics Calculator", font=('roboto', 20), command=lambda: page2.tkraise(), bg="#909090")
quadratics_btn.grid(pady=10)

simple_geometry_btn = tk.Button(page1, text="Geometry General", font=('roboto', 20), command=lambda: page3.tkraise(), bg="#909090")
simple_geometry_btn.grid(pady=10)

notYetImplemented_btn = tk.Button(page1, text="Not Yet Implemented", font=('roboto', 20), command=lambda: page4.tkraise(), bg="#909090")
notYetImplemented_btn.grid(pady=10)

#page going back buttons
back_btn = tk.Button(page2, text="Go back", font=('roboto', 20), command=lambda: page1.tkraise())
back_btn.grid()

back_btn = tk.Button(page3, text="Go back", font=('roboto', 20), command=lambda: page1.tkraise())
back_btn.grid()

back_btn = tk.Button(page4, text="Go back", font=('roboto', 20), command=lambda: page1.tkraise())
back_btn.grid()



page1.tkraise()

root.geometry("690x938")
root.title("Calculator Project (Beta 0.1)")
root.config(background="#545454")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.mainloop()

I know this code might seem a bit whacky, but I'm doing this as a little personal project of mine. Please just focus on my issue, any other suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance

To get what you want, you need to:

configure page1 to page4 to occupy the available space of the window:

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


create another frame inside each page and create those widgets inside that frame, then use pack(expand=1) on that frame to put it at the center of the parent frame pageX

Below is the modified code:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font

FONT20 = ('roboto', 20)
FONT24 = ('roboto', 24)
BGCOLOR = '#545454'
BTNCOLOR = '#909090'

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('690x938')
root.title('Calculator Project (Beta 0.1)')
root.resizable(0, 0)

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

page1 = tk.Frame(root, bg=BGCOLOR)
page2 = tk.Frame(root, bg=BGCOLOR)
page3 = tk.Frame(root, bg=BGCOLOR)
page4 = tk.Frame(root, bg=BGCOLOR)

page1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
page2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
page3.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
page4.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

##### Main Page
frame1 = tk.Frame(page1, bg=BGCOLOR)
frame1.pack(expand=1)  # center the frame

ttl1M = tk.Label(frame1, text='Main Page', font=FONT20, bg=BGCOLOR)
ttl1M.pack(pady=20)

quadratics_btn = tk.Button(frame1, text='Quadratics Calculator', font=FONT20, bg=BTNCOLOR, command=lambda: page2.tkraise())
quadratics_btn.pack(pady=10)

simple_geometry_btn = tk.Button(frame1, text='Geometry General', font=FONT20, bg=BTNCOLOR, command=lambda: page3.tkraise())
simple_geometry_btn.pack(pady=10)

not_yet_implemented_btn = tk.Button(frame1, text='Not Yet Implemented', font=FONT20, bg=BTNCOLOR, command=lambda: page4.tkraise())
not_yet_implemented_btn.pack(pady=10)

##### Page 2 - Quadratics
frame2 = tk.Frame(page2, bg=BGCOLOR)
frame2.pack(expand=1)  # center the frame

qdrtcs = tk.Label(frame2, text='Quadratics Page', font=FONT20, bg=BGCOLOR)
qdrtcs.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=20)

# spinboxes for A/B/C start
quad_a = tk.Spinbox(frame2, from_=-99, to=99, width=5, font=FONT24)
quad_a.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=30)

quad_b = tk.Spinbox(frame2, from_=-99, to=99, width=5, font=FONT24)
quad_b.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=30)

quad_c = tk.Spinbox(frame2, from_=-99, to=99, width=5, font=FONT24)
quad_c.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=30)

# go back button
back_btn = tk.Button(frame2, text='Go back', font=FONT20, command=lambda: page1.tkraise())
back_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3)

##### Page 3 - Geometry
frame3 = tk.Frame(page3, bg=BGCOLOR)
frame3.pack(expand=1)  # center the frame

nyi1 = tk.Label(frame3, text='Simple Geometry', font=FONT20, bg=BGCOLOR)
nyi1.pack(pady=20)

# go back button
back_btn = tk.Button(frame3, text='Go back', font=FONT20, command=lambda: page1.tkraise())
back_btn.pack()

##### Page 4 - not yet implemented
frame4 = tk.Frame(page4, bg=BGCOLOR)
frame4.pack(expand=1)  # center the frame

nyi2 = tk.Label(frame4, text='Under further construction', font=FONT20, bg=BGCOLOR)
nyi2.pack(pady=20)

# go back button
back_btn = tk.Button(frame4, text='Go back', font=FONT20, command=lambda: page1.tkraise())
back_btn.pack()

page1.tkraise()
root.mainloop()

Result for the first 2 pages:



Thank you! as a follow up, how do I retrieve those numbers as variables for further math equations?

@JstAguy Do you mean the values of the three spinboxes? If yes, call .get() on those widgets.

Changes made are given as comments inside the code with the phrase part of the solution :
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font
import math
import cmath

root = tk.Tk()  # application window
page1 = tk.Frame(root, background="#545454") 
page2 = tk.Frame(root, background="#545454")
page3 = tk.Frame(root, background="#545454")
page4 = tk.Frame(root, background="#545454")

# part of the solution : Configure rows and columns for widgets centering
# part of the solution : Added grid_rowconfigure
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# part of the solution : Used sticky="nsew"
page1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
page2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
page3.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
page4.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

for page in (page1, page2, page3, page4):

    # part of the solution : Configure rows and columns for widgets centering
    # part of the solution : Added grid_rowconfigure & grid_columnconfigure
    page.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    page.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# page titles
ttl1M = tk.Label(page1, text="Main Page", font=('roboto', 20), bg="#545454")

# part of the solution :  Used columnspan for labels across multiple columns
ttl1M.grid(pady=20, row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

# Quadratics Page-content
qdrtcs = tk.Label(page2, text="Quadratic Page", font=('roboto', 20), bg="#545454")

# part of the solution :  Used columnspan for labels across multiple columns
qdrtcs.grid(pady=20, padx=95, row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

# spinboxes for A/B/C start
quadA = tk.Spinbox(page2, from_=-99, to=99, width=5, font=('roboto', 24))
quadA.grid(pady=30, row=1, column=0, sticky="e")

quadB = tk.Spinbox(page2, from_=-99, to=99, width=5, font=('roboto', 24))
quadB.grid(pady=30, row=1, column=1, sticky="ew")

quadC = tk.Spinbox(page2, from_=-99, to=99, width=5, font=('roboto', 24))
quadC.grid(pady=30, row=1, column=2, sticky="w")

# Adjust column weights to ensure centering
page2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
page2.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
page2.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

##########
nyi1 = tk.Label(page3, text="Simple Geometry", font=('roboto', 20), bg="#545454")
nyi1.grid(pady=20, row=0, column=0)

nyi2 = tk.Label(page4, text="Under further construction", font=('roboto', 20), bg="#545454")
nyi2.grid(pady=20, row=0, column=0)

# page buttons
quadratics_btn = tk.Button(page1, text="Quadratics Calculator", font=('roboto', 20), command=lambda: page2.tkraise(), bg="#909090")
quadratics_btn.grid(pady=10, row=1, column=0)

simple_geometry_btn = tk.Button(page1, text="Geometry General", font=('roboto', 20), command=lambda: page3.tkraise(), bg="#909090")
simple_geometry_btn.grid(pady=10, row=2, column=0)

notYetImplemented_btn = tk.Button(page1, text="Not Yet Implemented", font=('roboto', 20), command=lambda: page4.tkraise(), bg="#909090")
notYetImplemented_btn.grid(pady=10, row=3, column=0)

# part of the solution : Adjust column weight to center the buttons
page1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# page going back buttons
back_btn = tk.Button(page2, text="Go back", font=('roboto', 20), command=lambda: page1.tkraise())
back_btn.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10)

back_btn = tk.Button(page3, text="Go back", font=('roboto', 20), command=lambda: page1.tkraise())
back_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)

back_btn = tk.Button(page4, text="Go back", font=('roboto', 20), command=lambda: page1.tkraise())
back_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)

page1.tkraise()

root.geometry("690x938")
root.title("Calculator Project (Beta 0.1)")
root.config(background="#545454")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.mainloop()

